# Error E QUERY [thread1] SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell) using and/or with find()

Tags: database, mongodb

I am getting the error while using this query 
    db.a.find({$or:[{"name" : "aekansh"},{"age" : 21}]}).pretty()

as
E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):1:11

collection a stores the data as

```
{ "_id" : 10, "name" : "aekansh" }
{ "_id" : 11, "name" : "ram" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59dda15e153802c1d1cf8500"), "name" : "ramu" }
{ "_id" : 12, "nm" : "raj", "age" : 21 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59dda1d26b740896d9f067a3"), "nm" : "rj", "age" : 22, "bfff" : "yes" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59dda1ea11fc6ddeb8784f7e"), "nm" : "rj1", "age" : 22, "bfff" : "yes" }
```

I have looked at syntax and I think it is right. Why I am getting the error. Thanx in advance.

Edit- I am using online terminal for MongoDb https://www.jdoodle.com/online-mongodb-terminal

Comment: Your query is correct, and it is working fine for the sample data provided.
Just ensure that you are using quotes for querying inner documents and strings, which is also there in your query. Try by closing the mongo shell and reopening the shell.

Comment: I am using online shell for mongoDB. https://www.jdoodle.com/online-mongodb-terminal . Is there any issue with this shell. Can you refer me a better terminal online.

Comment: I am also getting a similar error on jdoodle terminal. It seems the error is specific to this online terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned before your query is correct.

If fails on this online terminal it means terminal is buggy.

You have in fact 3 solutions about which I know:

1. Install MongoDB on your local computer and use MongoDB Compass or MongoShell to query your database.
2. Use [Mongo Web Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/insert-documents/) which is accessible on MongoDB documentation site.
3. The last option is to [set up free cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/atlas-free-tier-setup/) from Mongo site. They give you for free some space in cloud, set up database for you and as in first option  you can use MongoDB Compass or MongoShell to query it from you local computer.