# Comparison operators in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

This is a small list of records:

```
employee_id first_name  last_name   supervisor  hourly_pay     total_hours
1001        Andrew      Adams       Frank Smith $18.00      25
1002        Nancy       Edwards     Frank Smith $32.00      40
1003        Jane        Smith       Ted Jones   $16.00      18
1004        Margaret    Park        Ted Jones   $20.00      46
1005        Steve       Johnson     Ted Jones   $21.00      36
1006        Michael     Mitchell    Ted Jones   $28.00      36
1007        Robert      King        Ted Jones   $18.00      30
1008        Laura       Callahan    Ted Jones   $25.00      10
1009        Neena       Kochhar     Ted Jones   $36.00      15
1010        Lex         De Haan     Ted Jones   $25.00
```

These are a few codes I'm trying, but I always get errors:

```
db.employees.find( {"hourly_pay":{$lt:20}}) 

db.employees.find( {"hourly_pay": { $lte: 20 } } )

db.employees.find( {"hourly_pay": {$gt : 21 } } )
```

Comment: Hello, what error are you getting exactly? Are the values of `hourly_pay` perhaps strings with dollar signs, rather than numbers?

Comment: Hello, the error message is syntax error: invalid property id @shell:1:36, thank you for your help.

Comment: should I enter dollar signs and .00?

Comment: You should definitely just store the numbers, then your query should work as written.  Regarding your error message, I found this when googling it, not sure if it helps but maybe it does? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46681536/831878

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try.